# using a string in a math equation in Dart

Tags: dart

I store various formulas in Postgres and I want to use those formulas in my code. It would look something like this:

```
var amount = 100;
var formula = '5/105'; // normally something I would fetch from Postgres
var total = amount * formula; // should return 4.76
```

Is there a way to evaluate the string in this manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there isn't a formula solver package developed for Dart yet. (If one exists or gets created after this post, we can edit it into the answer.)

**EDIT: Mattia in the comments points out the [math_expressions](https://pub.dev/packages/math_expressions) package, which looks pretty robust and easy to use.**

There is a way to execute arbitrary Dart code as a string, but it has several problems. A] It's very roundabout and convoluted; B] it becomes a massive security issue; and C] it only works if the Dart is compiled in JIT mode (so in Flutter this means it will only work in debug builds, not release builds).

So the answer is that unfortunately, you will have to implement it yourself. The good news is that, for simple 4-function arithmetic, this is pretty straight-forward, and you can follow a tutorial on writing a calculator app [like this one](https://itnext.io/building-a-calculator-app-in-flutter-824254704fe6) to see how it's done.

Of course, if all your formulas only contain two terms with an operator between them like in your example snippet, it becomes even easier. You can do the whole thing in just a few lines of code:

```dart
void main() {
  final amount = 100;
  final formula = '5/105';

  final pattern = RegExp(r'(\d+)([\/+*-])(\d+)');
  final match = pattern.firstMatch(formula);
  final value = process(num.parse(match[1]), match[2], num.parse(match[3]));

  final total = amount * value;
  print(total); // Prints: 4.761904761904762
}

num process(num a, String operator, num b) {
  switch (operator) {
    case '+': return a + b;
    case '-': return a - b;
    case '*': return a * b;
    case '/': return a / b;
  }

  throw ArgumentError(operator);
}
```

Comment: There are several packages to parse a math expression in dart, here is one of them: https://pub.dev/packages/math_expressions

Comment: Though this solution works, it's limited to the specific formula. For instance, it wouldn't work with something like '5/105*0.5'. However, I did find a few packages that handle this. 

- https://pub.dev/packages/function_tree
- https://pub.dev/packages/expressions
- https://pub.dev/packages/math_expressions

I ended up using `function_tree`, though I was also able to do it with `math_expressions`.

Comment: @Lee I did preface the code in this answer with the text "if all your formulas only contain two terms with an operator between them like in your example snippet". Your example contains 3 terms and 2 operators, so obviously it won't work (though it could easily be extended to, although at that point order of operations also becomes a concern).

Comment: @Abion47, for sure, wasn't meant as a criticism. :-)  I have implemented a solution using a Dart package and was wondering what the proper etiquette would be to include that solution here for other people?

Comment: @Lee Post your own answer with your solution.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few packages that can be used to accomplish this:

- [pub.dev/packages/function_tree](https://pub.dev/packages/function_tree)
- [pub.dev/packages/math_expressions](https://pub.dev/packages/math_expressions)
- [pub.dev/packages/expressions](https://pub.dev/packages/expressions)

I used `function_tree` as follows:

```
double amount = 100.55;
String formula = '5/105*.5'; // From Postgres

final tax = amount * formula.interpret();
```

I haven't tried it, but using `math_expressions` it should look like this:

```
double amount = 100.55;
String formula = '5/105*.5'; // From Postgres

Parser p = Parser();
// Context is used to evaluate variables, can be empty in this case.
ContextModel cm = ContextModel();

Expression exp = p.parse(formula) * p.parse(amount.toString());
// or..
//Expression exp = p.parse(formula) * Number(amount);

double result = exp.evaluate(EvaluationType.REAL, cm);

// Result: 2.394047619047619
print('Result: ${result}');
```

Thanks to [fkleon](http://github.com/fkleon) for the `math_expressions` help.